# Creating an array of Deques

Tags: java, arrays, deque

I need to create and use an array of Deques, something like the following

```
Deque<Point>[] saved = new LinkedList<Point>[12];
```

This code results in an error because Java doesn't allow you to create generic arrays of Deques. Is there a way to set up the array of Deques so I can access each individual Deque when I need to? 
 
I also tried:

```
Deque<Point>[] saved;
//....
for(int i = 0;i<12;i++)
{
     saved[i] = new LinkedList<Point>;
}
```

which returns a NullPointerException. How can I create this array?

Comment: @Jens I'm afraid not, I get the same "Cannot create a generic array of Deque<Point>"

Comment: you can do `Deque<Point>[] saved = new Deque[12];` ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `saved` to an `ArrayList`:

```
// Note that saved has a size defined at construction, 
// which makes this efficient. 
final List<Deque<Point>> saved = new ArrayList<Deque<Point>>(12);
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
   saved.add(new LinkedList<Point>());
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid, I get the same complaint about not being able to create a generic array of Deque<Point>

Comment: Ah, of course.  An `ArrayList` with a size defined at construction should work well. Updated the answer.

Comment: @imulsion There is no array creation in that code.  What line of code is giving you that error?

Comment: The updated solution worked perfectly. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use  [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)?

You can use this :

```
ArrayDeque arr = new ArrayDeque<Point>(12);
```

Or this :

```
LinkedList l = new LinkedList<Point>();
ArrayDeque arr = new ArrayDeque(l);
```

There are a good tutorial here [Java.util.ArrayDeque Class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_arraydeque.htm)

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing. ArrayDeque is a Fast Deque Operations Using an Array.